# How do I get an OAuth2 refresh token in Google Chrome Packaged Apps?

Tags: oauth2, chrome

### Background

I am creating a Google Chrome Packaged App that allows users to access various features from a plurality of salesforce.com organizations. This app will allow users to perform various tasks depending on their permissions in each organization, such as querying data and logging in with a single click. To avoid storing passwords, I'm trying to use OAuth2 to generate refresh tokens that can be used to access those organizations, with a mechanism to revoke those tokens if needed across all organizations in the event of a compromise.

### Problem

Generating a refresh token only happens in certain flows that follow a certain pattern, and those patterns seem to be incompatible with Google's "chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow" mechanism.

### Attempted Solutions

So far, I have tried the following end-points to try and get Google Chrome to recognize that we've successfully completed the flow and obtain a refresh token. Here are my attempts so far:

```
/services/oauth2/authorize?
grant_type=code&
client_id=XYZ&
prompt=login&
scope=full+refresh_token&
redirect_uri=https://<appid>.chromiumapp.org/callback
```

This link follows the web server flow. We get a code back that we can use to call /services/oauth2/tokens, but ths requires the client_secret, which we are not supposed to embed in the code for security reasons-- the source code is open.

```
/services/oauth2/authorize?
grant_type=token&
client_id=XYZ&
prompt=login&
scope=full+refresh_token&
redirect_uri=https://<appid>.chromiumapp.org/callback
```

This link won't give us a refresh_token, because it does not have a custom protocol and does not match login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success.

```
/services/oauth2/authorize?
grant_type=token&
client_id=XYZ&
prompt=login&
scope=full+refresh_token&
redirect_uri=chrome-extension://<appid>/callback
```

This link results in an error in Google Chrome about not being able to load the authorization page, but would give us a refresh token if it worked.

```
/services/oauth2/authorize?
grant_type=token&
client_id=XYZ&
prompt=login&
scope=full+refresh_token&
redirect_uri=https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success
```

This page doesn't actually show an access token or error, so Google Chrome never detects that the flow is complete. We do not get an access token or refresh token. I have a feeling this is is the proper flow to use, but without a way to detect the token, it simply doesn't work. The authorization page simply sits open forever once we reach this step.

### Question

How am I supposed to code this app such that it securely accesses salesforce.com without compromising the client_secret while preventing excessive login attempts and/or API calls from a periodic timer that would be required?

I realize that this question may be outside the scope of this forum, but this seems to be fairly salesforce.com specific, as other OAuth2 sites work just fine with chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow, so I thought I'd ask here and see if anyone knows enough about Chrome and OAuth2 as it pertains to accessing salesforce.com.

### Cross-Posted

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/APIs-and-Integration/How-do-I-get-an-OAuth2-refresh-token-in-Google-Chrome-Packaged/m-p/695323

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using OAuth2 with salesforce.com in a packaged app, you need to use a "webview" element and listen for the appropriate events. Here are the portions of the source that are relevant to the solution:

### Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
    <body>
<!-- content required to have page eventually display interactive oauth2 -->
        <webview style="display: none; ... (set a nice width/height)" id="oauth2"></webview>
    </body>
</html>
```

### JavaScript

```
(function() {
    var outh2frame;
    function showOAuth2Frame() {
        oauth2frame.style.display = 'block';
        oauth2frame.src = 'https://login.salesforce.com...';
    }
    function onWebViewLoadStart(event) {
        if(event.url.indexOf('/services/oauth2/success#')>-1) {
            // we've got success. Load the tokens and hide the frame.
        }
    }
    function onLoad(event) {
        oauth2frame = document.querySelector('#oauth2');
        oauth2frame.addEventListener('loadstart', onWebViewLoadStart);
    }
    addEventListener('load', onLoad, true);
}());
```

You also need to add the appropriate permission to your package in order to use a webview.

Answer (score -1):

Any chance you could share the solution? I am struggling with the same thing and I am getting an undefined response from the chrome identity call to my constructed URL.

Comment: Welcome to the [Salesforce Stack Exchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/about). This is not an answer to the question, but is more of a comment.  Once you have enough reputation from participating in the site you can [comment on other people's posts](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).